# Can I use low-temperature cooking for foie gras

Tags: baking, slow-cooking, duck

I used to cook my meat (beef, duck) at 58°C, but I never cooked foie gras of myself. Is it possible to use this cooking method for this?

I am wondering this because I saw a recipe with a beef piece half-opened with a raw foie gras inserted in. Then all of this baked but with normal cooking temperature+time and I would like to try low-temperature cooking.

Thank you

Comment: You provided a temperature, but asked about a method.  What is your method? What would be your concern?

Comment: Furnace at 65°C and initialy cold, bake until the center of the meat reachs 58°C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine if you your product is in the oven until the center reaches 58C.  Carry over cooking will cause the temp to increase slightly, and your fois will be in the safe zone.